# What is the difference between [Conditional("DEBUG")] and [ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]?

Tags: .net

What is the difference between [Conditional("DEBUG")]  and [ConditionalAttribute("DEBUG")]. Are both same or technically any difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C#, attributes are not required to have their `Attribute` suffix of their class name.